# Error importing matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, enthought

When I run `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, I get the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-6f467123fe04> in <module>()
----> 1 import matplotlib.pyplot

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in <module>()
     21 from matplotlib.cbook import dedent, silent_list, is_string_like, is_numlike
     22 from matplotlib import docstring
---> 23 from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
     24 from matplotlib.backend_bases import FigureCanvasBase
     25 from matplotlib.image import imread as _imread

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in <module>()
     16 import artist
     17 from artist import Artist, allow_rasterization
---> 18 from axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
     19 from cbook import flatten, allequal, Stack, iterable, is_string_like
     20 import _image

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes.py in <module>()
     12 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     13 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
---> 14 import matplotlib.axis as maxis
     15 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     16 import matplotlib.collections as mcoll

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py in <module>()
      8 from matplotlib.artist import allow_rasterization
      9 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
---> 10 import matplotlib.font_manager as font_manager
     11 import matplotlib.lines as mlines
     12 import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/font_manager.py in <module>()
     50 import matplotlib
     51 from matplotlib import afm
---> 52 from matplotlib import ft2font
     53 from matplotlib import rcParams, get_configdir
     54 from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.so
  Reason: image not found
```

My `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools.pth` is this: `/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/Python`. My `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth` is as following:

```
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg
/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/7.3/Python
./pudb-2012.3-py2.7.egg
./Pygments-1.5-py2.7.egg
./urwid-1.0.2-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:]; p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

What should I to import `matplotlib.pyplot` correctly? I have homebrew installed, am running the Enthought Python Distribution, and am running OSX.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! What I did was the following: I deleted (after making a backup) the matplotlib folder in my system's site-packages folder (`/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages`).