# Pylab ImportError - Library not loaded - confusing directory structure of Mountain Lion?

Tags: python, macos

I wrote a little program while I was using my previous computer (my previous work's computer) which was a  Windows machine. Now, based on the advice of a friend, I got a Mac, but I've had a hell of a time getting stuff to work on it.

In particular, my program uses pylab (part of matplotlib), and I am having an ImportError after `import pylab`:

```
Error: ~/Documents/New folder/Programowanie/Projekt/SimAccents_v2d.py:2: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py:1: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pylab.py:222: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl.py:2: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:14: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/text.py:29: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py:47: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py:11: 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py:61: ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib
```

I tried `import matplotlib` in Python IDLE, which worked, so apparently the problem is with pylab, not matplotlib. However, I tried `import matplotlib.pyplot` and got pretty much the same error, which I guess is because they are quite similar modules/pieces of matplotlib.

I have done a good deal of digging on the internet, and found a few potentially useful things, but the result has been more confusion. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292396/error-importing-matplotlib-pyplot) appears to be a similar problem to mine, which the author solved by "deleting (after making a backup) the matplotlib folder in my system's site-packages folder (/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages)". I expect that the reason that this may have worked is that perhaps Python is looking in the wrong place for the file.

To check this, I used the way of finding out matplotlib's install location:

```
>>> import matplotlib
>>> matplotlib.__file__
'/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc'
```

...and matplotlib's directory location:

```
>>> matplotlib.get_configdir()
'/Uses/stanislawpstrokonski/.matplotlib'
```

Investigating these paths, I found that the second one is a hidden folder which contains only two files - .DS_Store (hidden) and fontList.cache. The first directory, however, was a bit more spooky, as Python says that that directory, including the final "problem" file of the error message above, exists:

```
>>> os.path.isfile('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so')
True
```

...but I have been unable to find ~/Library/Frameworks on my Mac, as it both doesn't appear in Finder, and Mac OS Terminal can't seem to find it either:

```
Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~ stanislawpstrokonski$ cd ~/Library/Frameworks
-bash: cd: /Users/stanislawpstrokonski/Library/Frameworks: No such file or directory
```

It's exactly the same story for /Library/Python - Python confirms its existence, but Terminal denies it. However, when I type in this code to Terminal, it decides that the path does exist after all:

```
Stanislaws-MacBook-Pro:~ stanislawpstrokonski$ cd /usr/bin; ls -l python2.7
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 16 Nov 16:30 python2.7 ->  ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
```

Another thing I checked was the `Library not loaded:` path from the original ImportError:

```
>>> os.path.isfile('/opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib')
False
```

So perhaps the problem is that I am missing this path? What am I supposed to do about this? Isn't matplotlib meant to sort this sort of stuff out when it is installed?

I don't know why pylab is misbehaving, when wxPython and numpy (and, apparently, matplotlib aside from pylab and pyplot) appear to be working just fine. I also am baffled by Mac OS X's directory structure, although I still have a feeling that this may be the source of the problem. Another reason could be that I have installed Python on my machine, but I have heard that Mac OS already has Python installed, so maybe the two are confusing each other somehow.

I'm sorry that this post is so long, but when I don't know exactly where the problem is, I feel like I have to write down everything. Could anyone help me get pylab working, and perhaps enlighten me about Macs in the process? I would be extremely grateful.

p.s. I am using Mountain Lion and I bought my Mac about two weeks ago.

p.p.s. [This person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14126876/fixing-import-error-when-importing-pylab-on-mountain-lion) seems to be having a similar problem, though it's a different bit that isn't importing...

Comment: The same problem. You have libpng it is in:  /usr/local/Cellar/libpng/... but I can not find the way where I can change path in matplotlib from image.py case it links at matplotlib._image
I don't know what to do..

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with matplotlib on OS X. You just need to install libpng. I've used [brew](http://mxcl.github.io/homebrew/): `brew install libpng`.